# Error creating ActionCadence via Salesforce API

Tags: api, python

I'm looking to create an [ActionCadence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_actioncadence.htm?q=ActionCadence) (Salesforce Cadence) using the object reference documentation. It states that in version 58, you should be able to "create()"

**Based on the error code I receive, I've been lead to believe that I'm not actually able to create this via API.**

That said, when running the following code

```
import requests
import simple_salesforce
import json
import logging
from auth import sfdc_auth


def create_action_cadence():
    sfdc_client = sfdc_auth()
    
    input = {'Name': 'NewProgrammaticCadence'}

    action_cadence = sfdc_client.restful(
        method='POST',
        path='sobjects/ActionCadence',
        json=input,
    )

    print(action_cadence)
    return action_cadence

cadence = create_action_cadence()
```

I get the following output.

`simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceMalformedRequest: Malformed request https://exampleinstancename.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/ActionCadence. Response content: [{'message': 'entity type cannot be inserted: Cadence', 'errorCode': 'CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY', 'fields': []}]`

That said my experience with Salesforce is extremely limited so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Have you checked that the user you're using to make this call has access in Salesforce to create ActionCadence records?

Comment: try setting `State` to `Draft`

Comment: @cropredy - Tried setting the state to draft and still getting the same error, unfortunately. The documentation makes it really hard to discern what is actually a required input as opposed to not based on the action you're trying to perform.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich - I am able to create in the UI and am using my user to authenticate to the API so I would assume I have the right permissions. I confirmed I also have the Sales Engagement Cadence Creator permission associated with my user so I don't think it's a permissions issue. I'm able to run the GET command without any issues on the API endpoint so I know it's also not an endpoint issue.

Comment: If you create in the UX, you can do a  SOQL query to see all of the fields that are set; this might help determine the requisite POST body